# Intersystems Cache: An aggregate function cannot be used in a WHERE or GROUP BY clause

Tags: sql, intersystems-cache

I am learning Intersystems Cache and have the following Function which I based off code running an earlier version of the product (I am 17.2).

```
Query dueToday(rToday As DType.Date) As %SQLQuery(ROWSPEC = "Book:User.Books,RefNo:%Integer")
{
    SELECT BookODue.Rent, BookODue.RefNo
      FROM BookODue
      LEFT JOIN BookTran
      ON BookODue.Rent = BookTran.Rent
      WHERE (BookODue.AuditDate = :rToday) AND (MAX(BookTran.TranDate) < :rToday)
}
```

When I compile this I get

> An aggregate function cannot be used in a WHERE or GROUP BY clause

Any help appreciated.

Gracias

Comment: The error is self-explanatory.  `MAX()` is not permitted in a `WHERE` clause.  What don't you understand?  You haven't provided sample data, desired results, or explained what you want to do, so it really isn't possible to suggest a working query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could speculate that you really want:

```
SELECT bo.Rent, bo.RefNo
FROM BookODue bo JOIN
     BookTran bt
     ON bo.Rent = bt.Rent
WHERE bo.AuditDate = :rToday
GROUP BY bo.Rent, bo.RefNo
HAVING MAX(bt.TranDate) < :rToday;
```